# Program which source code is exactly the same as its output

Tags: c, printf, output, quine

The more I try to understand this perplexed enigma the more I want to give up.

```
char *s = "char *s = %c%s%c; main(){printf(s,34,s,34);}"; main(){printf(s,34,s,34);}
```

How is happening for this one-line source code to generate exactly the same output when the program executes and is there any common notion for this kind of programs?

Comment: Do you know what `printf` does?  Can you work out what `printf("char *s = %c%s%c; main(){printf(s,34,s,34);}", 34, "char *s = %c%s%c; main(){printf(s,34,s,34);}", 34)` prints, given that 34 is the ASCII code for a `"`?

Comment: Now it is official - I am terribly lacking analyzing skills.

Comment: I know what 34 is and what printf does.. it just semantically confuses me.

Comment: @Malina  34 is the ASCII code for `"`, the code uses `34` instead of `'"'` as to avoid having to escape the quote character.

Comment: Since you have the code, did you try [searching for it](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=main%28%29%7Bprintf%28s%2C34%2Cs%2C34%29%3B%7D) here on stack overflow. **Lots** of related material to look through!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is called a [Quine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)).

So let's see what `main()` does:

```
printf(s,34,s,34);
```

34 is the ASCII code for the character `"` (double quote), so this is the same as:

```
printf(s, '"', s, '"');
```

The first argument to `printf(3)` is the format string. The string passed is:

```
"char *s = %c%s%c; main(){printf(s,34,s,34);}"
```

So, `printf(3)` will output exactly that, but note the `%c`, `%s` and `%c` format specifiers, which instruct `printf(3)` to print a character, followed by a string, followed by another character in that place, which are respectively the 2nd, 3rd and 4th arguments.

The characters, as we saw, are both `"`, and the string is `s` again (the same string). So the program output is:

```
char *s = "X"; main(){printf(s,34,s,34);}
```

Where `X` is the string `s` in the program. So we get this as output:

```
char *s = "char *s = %c%s%c; main(){printf(s,34,s,34);}"; main(){printf(s,34,s,34);}
```

Which, interestingly, is the program source itself.

Comment: Inevitably explanatory-obfuscated; so I think not giving this to students is a wonderful idea. Thanks :)

Comment: @Malina Indeed, it may be trickyfor the untrained student eye, but self-replicating programs are an important part of computability theory. Students should at least learn the concept.

Comment: I've also updated the question to make it more valuable to others reading your answer in parallel with the addition.

Comment: @Malina Thanks, it's always good to clarify the question so that others can find it easily. I readded the `quine` tag to your question as it seems you (accidentally?) removed it. I think this is an appropriate tag for your question, but if you disagree, then by all means feel free to undo my actions.

Comment: I do feel free, but it was just to not cause confusion towards people "He tagged with something he was asking for??" to avoid people thinking it was a semi self-answered question if you get what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

take that string from first parameter of printf:

```
'char *s = %c%s%c; main(){printf(s,34,s,34);}'
```

and do substitution where

```
%c = 34 = '"' //(same for both %c)
%s = 'char *s = %c%s%c; main(){printf(s,34,s,34);}'
```

printf will do substitution only once (not recursive), so result is:

```
'char *s = "char *s = %c%s%c; main(){printf(s,34,s,34);}"; main(){printf(s,34,s,34);}'
```

Answer (score 1):

To understand the code, first simplify and reformat:

```
char *s = "some format string";
main() {
    printf(s,34,s,34);
}
```

so it uses `s` as a formatting string to print three entities: `34`, the string `s` itself and `34`.  In this case, the important part of the formatting string `s` is:

```
char *s = "... %c%s%c ..."
```

which means the two `34`s become double-quotes (`"`) and the formatting-string `s` is just printed as a normal string.  Now you should see the the *rest* of the formatting-string `s` is just a copy of the whole program.